# StencilJS Unit Testing using Jest throwing error

Tags: jestjs, stenciljs

Jest unit test case for listening `click` event emitted from child is throwing error

```
expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalled()

Expected number of calls: >= 1
Received number of calls:    0
```

// .spec.ts code

```js
import { newSpecPage } from '@stencil/core/testing';
import { MyComponent } from './my-component';
import { MyEmbeddedComponent } from './my-embedded-component';

describe('click event', () => {
  let page;
  beforeEach(async () => {
    page = await newSpecPage({
      components: [MyComponent, MyEmbeddedComponent],
      html: '<my-component color="green"></my-component>'
    });
  });

  it('should emit click event', async () => {
    let callbackFn = jest.fn();

    page.doc.addEventListener('clickCompleted', callbackFn);
    const button = page.root.shadowRoot.querySelector('button');
    await button.dispatchEvent(new Event('clickCompleted'));
    await page.waitForChanges();
    expect(callbackFn).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

// my-embedded-component.ts

```js
import { Component, Prop, h, Event, EventEmitter } from '@stencil/core';

@Component({
  tag: 'my-embedded-component'
})
export class MyEmbeddedComponent {
  @Prop() color: string;

  @Event() clickCompleted: EventEmitter;
  handleClickCompleted() {
    console.log('Emitting clickCompleted event');
    this.clickCompleted.emit(4);
  }

  render() {
    return <button onClick={this.handleClickCompleted.bind(this)}>I'm a child</button>;
  }
}
```

// my-component.tsx

```js
import { Component, h, Listen } from '@stencil/core';

@Component({
  tag: 'my-component',
  styleUrl: 'my-component.css',
  shadow: true
})
export class MyComponent {
  @Listen('clickCompleted')
  listenClickCompleted(e: CustomEvent) {
    console.log('Listening listenClickCompleted ', e.detail);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div class="hello">
        <my-embedded-component color="green"></my-embedded-component>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I recommend a different approach to testing this kind of thing. Testing that an event is dispatched by directly dispatching the event isn't really testing (even though in this case it fails). The designed functionality is what you should test - clicking the button dispatches the event. So instead of calling `dispatchEvent` click the button:

```
let callbackFn = jest.fn();
page.doc.addEventListener('clickCompleted', callbackFn);
const button = page.root.shadowRoot.querySelector('button');
await button.click();
expect(callbackFn).toHaveBeenCalled();
```